# Code or function for control object with unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have script c# that already installed in one of the object component in Unity. This script is to controlling the object that have same function, the difference is for every objects.

I made this script is working on demand but unfortunately I thought this script is not efficently if I have so many same objects with the same function.

Is there anyone can help me to simplify and optimizing that script? I've already doing the searching reference that almost similiar with my case but I can't implement it in my script.
Thank you before for any help

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]

public class ControllerStage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float s1;
    public float s2;
    private Sprite FULLHP, LESSHP, LESSERHP, NOHP;
    private Object[] textures;
    private GameObject btnstage1, btnstage2;
    private Image image1,image2;

    void Start()
    {
        s1 = s2 = 0;
        stage1();
        stage2();
        textures = Resources.LoadAll ("Sprites/sprite2");
        FULLHP = (Sprite)textures [32];
        LESSHP = (Sprite)textures [31];
        LESSERHP = (Sprite)textures [30];
        NOHP = (Sprite)textures [29];

        // Delete this when you know it's working :)
        // if(Debug.isDebugBuild)
        // {
        //     Debug.Log("FULLHP = " + FULLHP);
        //     Debug.Log("LESSHP = " + LESSHP);
        //     Debug.Log("LESSERHP = " + LESSERHP);
        //     Debug.Log("NOHP = " + NOHP);
        // }
    }

        void stage1()
        {

            btnstage1 = GameObject.Find("btnstage1");

            if (!(image1 = btnstage1.GetComponent<Image>()))
                Debug.Log("I have no Image component! Fix meeeeeeeeeeeee");

            switch(s1){
              case 3:
                image1.sprite = FULLHP;
              break;
              case 2:
                image1.sprite = LESSHP;
              break;
              case 1:
                image1.sprite = LESSERHP;
              break;
              case 0:
              default:
                image1.sprite = NOHP;
              break;
            }
        }

        void stage2()
        {
            btnstage2 = GameObject.Find("btnstage2");

            if (!(image2 = btnstage2.GetComponent<Image>()))
                Debug.Log("I have no Image component! Fix meeeeeeeeeeeee");

            switch(s2){
              case 3:
                image2.sprite = FULLHP;
              break;
              case 2:
                image2.sprite = LESSHP;
              break;
              case 1:
                image2.sprite = LESSERHP;
              break;
              case 0:
              default:
                image2.sprite = NOHP;
              break;
            }
        }

    void Update()
    {
        stage1();
        stage2();
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit unclear what you are asking here. In general some notes: A) Don't use `Find` every frame in `Update`! This is extremely expensive. Rather store the references **once**. B) Due to floating point imprecision you shouldn't use a `switch-case` for floats. Either make these `int`s or rather use `if(Mathf.Approximately(s1, 1))` etc. C) In general you shouldn't constantly poll-check some values and all the time set the images .. rather make your code more event driven. E.g. instead of simply set the float value rather have something like `public void SetS1(float value){ ... }`

Comment: @derHugo thank you for your feedback. 
The code is for the configuration of each button, for example btnstage1 for level 1, btnstage2 for level 2 and so on. I think the same action only has a different value.

is it possible if I make it btnstage_N for level N, the method that I use right now is not right, do you have any suggestions that I can use?